# Rerendering Apex tabs

Tags: apex

Why doesn't this run the method in my controller when I click on the tab?

VisualForce Page

```
<apex:actionFunction name="clickCaseBlock" action="{!clickCaseBlock}" rerender="CaseBlockSection"/>
  <apex:tab label="Case Block Email" name="Case_Block_Email" id="Case_Block_Email" ontabenter="clickCaseBlock();">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="CaseBlockSection">

                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCase}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!caseList}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onSelect}" rerender="values"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel id="values">
                        <table style="width:50%">
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:outputText value="Some Text"/></td>
                                <td><apex:inputField value="{!Object.Field}"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!onSave}" rerender="values"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel> 

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:tab>
```

Controller

```
public void clickCaseBlock(){
    System.debug('==========CaseBlock==========');
    if(caseBlockEmailList == null) caseBlockEmailList = new List<SelectOption>();
    caseBlockEmailList.clear();

    instanceListCaseBlockEmail = [SELECT Name, Id, Block_Email_Address__c FROM Case_Block_Email__c];

    for(Case_Block_Email__c instanceCaseBlockEmail : instanceListCaseBlockEmail){
        caseBlockEmailList.add(new SelectOption(instanceCaseBlockEmail.Name, instanceCaseBlockEmail.Name));
    }

    if(instanceListCaseBlockEmail != null && !instanceListCaseBlockEmail.isEmpty())
        caseBlockEmailInstance = instanceListCaseBlockEmail[0];

}
```

EDIT:
I've added the VisualForce page above. Basically every time I click this tab I want to to fire the method in my controller and populate the outputfields

Comment: It looks like the method would be called, but you're not rendering the right area. Make sure that the id matches the rerender attribute.

Comment: `<apex:pageBlockSection id="CaseBlockSection">`

Comment: ^^^ Anything under this section I am rerendering. But whenever I click on a tab it doesn't call the method in my controller.

Comment: @Kush Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for.